# How to run Python code in Azure Databricks from local client

Tags: python-3.x, azure-databricks

I have this situation to solve and I am not sure how to proceed.

We have a Databricks instance running on Microsoft Azure. On Databricks, there also are multiple databases which can be accessed with Databricks' Apache Spark client (PySpark). We have a working code which runs fine when running directly in Databricks.
How do we connect our local clients (or pipelines in Microsoft Azure Development?) to execute the code in Databricks?

The idea is to come up with a solution on how to run the code, which can only be ran in Databricks, from local clients or from the pipeline?

I have looked into Databricks Connect but that does not seem like a library which could solve our issue.

Thank you